# jQuery ajax to PHP, returning Error and empty object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to use jQuery ajax to call PHP and return JSON.

My test is very simple, but all I seem to be getting is an empty object.

I am not getting any PHP errors in the LOG File.

jqXHR is shown as an object with the 'alert', but does not appear in the 'Chrome' console.

The 'Unpacked' alert does not show at all

I have obviously missed something or made some stupid error, but I can not see what I have done wrong.

HTML

```
<body>
<form id="frmSearch" onsubmit="matchQryString();">
    Search: <input type="text" name="qryWords" value="" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function matchQryString() {
        alert("Running AJAX");
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'rtnJSON.php',
            data:$('#frmSearch').serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                alert("PHP Return SUCCESS");
                alert(response);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                alert("PHP Return ERROR");
                alert(jqXHR);
                alert(exception);
                console.log(jqXHR);
                var op = "";
                for (property in jqXHR) {
                    op += property + ': ' + obj[property]+'; ';
                }
                alert ("Unpacked: " + op);
            }
        });
       return false ;
    }
</script>
</body>
```

PHP

```
<?php

  $arr = array ('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5);

  header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');

  echo json_encode($arr); // {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}

?>
```

Comment: obj[property] - where is obj defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form` being submitted before `$.ajax()` call ? Try removing `onsubmit` from `html` , `type="submit"` from `input` element , attaching `click` event to `type="submit"` element , calling `.e.preventDefault()` within `click` handler . Also note, `obj` does not appear defined within `error` handler of `$.ajax()`

html

```
<form id="frmSearch"">
    Search: <input type="text" name="qryWords" value="" />
   <input type="button" name="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

js

```
$(function() {
      function matchQryString(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Running AJAX");
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'rtnJSON.php',
            data:$('#frmSearch').serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                alert("PHP Return SUCCESS");
                alert(response);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                alert("PHP Return ERROR");
                alert(jqXHR);
                alert(exception);
                console.log(jqXHR);
                var op = "";
                for (property in jqXHR) {

                    op += property + ': ' + obj[property]+'; ';
                }
                alert ("Unpacked: " + op);
            }
        });
    };

    $("[name=submit]").on("click", matchQryString);
})
```

Comment: Many thanks.  It did not work initially with e.preventDefault() at the start of the function `matchQryString()`.  When I commented it out - it worked as I thought it would.  Where should I position the `e.preventDefault()` call ?

Comment: @mcl _"It did not work initially with e.preventDefault() at the start of the function matchQryString(). When I commented it out - it worked as I thought it would. Where should I position the e.preventDefault() call ? "_ If `e.preventDefault()` not needed to return expected result , leave omitted ?

Comment: Apologies : silly me missed the addition of e being passed to function